# Delegate interface implementation to a member

Tags: scala, inheritance

I would like to extend a class `Mesh`, and I would prefer not using inheritance for this, but a member instead (I want this because I already have many classes derived from `Mesh`). I would like to [delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) most (perhaps all?) member functions to the original implementation. I can explicitely redirect them one by one, but perhaps there is some more concise way? At the very minimum I would like to avoid having to repeat the parameter lists for the functions.

Or perhaps an implicit conversion from ExtMesh to Mesh would handle the "old" interface (without using the `extend Mesh`), allowing me to only add new functionality?

```
abstract class Mesh {
  def Func1(a:Int, b:Float, c:String) : Unit
  def Func2(a:Float, b:Float, c:Int) : Int
}


class ExtMesh extends Mesh {
  Mesh mesh
  def Func1(a:Int, b:Float, c:String) = mesh.Func1(a, b, c)
  def Func2(a:Float, b:Float, c:Int) = mesh.Func2(a, b, c)

  def ExtFunc3(a:String, b:Float)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or perhaps an implicit conversion from ExtMesh to Mesh would handle the "old" interface (without using the extend Mesh), allowing me to only add new functionality?

I learned meanwhile this is quite easy, as one can provide implicit conversions in a companion object:

```
class ExtMesh {
  Mesh mesh

  def ExtFunc3(a:String, b:Float)
}

object ExtMesh {
  implicit def toMesh(ext:ExtMesh): Mesh = ext.mesh
}
```

This allows me to call functions of `Mesh` on `ExtMesh` object or to use `ExtMesh` where `Mesh` is expected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this should be possible. The idea of an abstract function is to *force* an implementation of that function. You have to give the compiler something.

If you want `ExtMesh` to provide a rich interface to `Mesh` than the idiomatic approach would be an implicit conversion -- however *from* `Mesh` *to* `ExtMesh`.

Maybe you should extend the question a little bit to show your actual problem. It is a bit suspicious that you do not want to write a few wrapper functions. Is the number of abstract members that large? Could you implement your abstract class as a trait instead, with only a small number of abstract functions and reuse them to fully implement other members?

Comment: "The idea of an abstract function is to force an implementation" I understand that. There are however already some (several) existing implementations of Mesh (like Sphere, Cylinder) I can use to implement the interface. Perhaps there is some different approach, maybe using generics? And yes, the interface is quite large (more than 50 functions, many with multiple arguments).

Comment: Actually my real use case is even more complicated in that there is no abstract class, there is concrete class [Mesh](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/com/jme3/scene/Mesh.html) and a few derived classes, however even scenario like in question is something I already encountered, and so far I was always solving it by repeating the code - however that was in C++, and I hoped Scala might provide some facilities how to do this in more concise way.

Comment: @Suma: 50 abstract functions is indeed a lot, and very uncommon in Scala, where this is typically avoided by using traits. Often you can reduce the core functionality to a small set of abstract members (say 5), and implement literally hundreds of other functions derived from the core functionality. If this is not possible in your case, you either have to inherit directly or write the wrapper code...

Answer (score 0):

Delegation in Scala can be done using macros. See 
[Automatic generation of delegate methods with Macro Annotations](http://www.warski.org/blog/2013/09/automatic-generation-of-delegate-methods-with-macro-annotations/)

Another option is to use extension trait with self type, as shown in [Real delegation in Scala](http://kofler.nonblocking.at/2013/08/real-delegation-in-scala/).

```
trait ExtMesh { this : Mesh =>
  def ExtFunc3(a:String, b:Float)
}

val extMesh = new Mesh with ExtMesh
```