# Exposing defs from member object?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a trait like so:

```
trait A {
  def x: Long
  def y: Long
}
```

And I have a class which takes an A and needs to be an A:

```
case class B(a: A, foo: Foo, bar: Bar) extends A {
  override def x = a.x
  override def y = a.y
}
```

If A had lots of members, this would get annoying quickly. Is there a pattern that lets me "decorate" A with a foo and a bar?

Comment: This reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893462/delegate-interface-implementation-to-a-member

Comment: Can you describe in more detail why do you need B to "be" `A`? Would behaving as `A` or providing a conversion to `A` be enough?

Comment: It turns out that I _can_ let B behave as an A, and the implicit conversion solution works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with such code, i don't know if it would be of any use for you:

```
object SelfAnnotationExample extends App{

  trait A {
   def x: Lon
   def y: Long
  }

  trait ExtendedA extends A { self: InstanceProvider[A] =>
    def x: Long = self.instance.x
    def y: Long = self.instance.y
  }

  trait InstanceProvider[A] {
    def instance: A
  }

  case class B(instance: A, foo: Any) extends ExtendedA with InstanceProvider[A]
  case class TestA(x: Long, y: Long) extends A

  val test = B(TestA(3, 4), 23)
  println(test.x)
  println(test.y)
}
```

I use scala feature known as "self type" (Someone correct me if i named it wrong). Trait InstanceProvider is not limited for this particular case. This solution need additional trait ExtendedA definition but every concrete implementation of A can utilize it.

Comment: I think `ExtendedA ` is again what OP wanted to avoid: repeating each member in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call members from `A` on `B` and want to pass the `A` part of `B` to functions expecting `A`, you can achieve it using implicit conversion from `B` to `A`:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Main extends App{

  trait A {
    def x: Long
    def y: Long
  }

  def processA(a: A) = ()


  class Foo
  class Bar
  case class B(a: A, foo: Foo, bar: Bar)

  implicit def bToA(b: B): A = b.a

  case class TestA(x: Long, y: Long) extends A

  val test = B(TestA(3, 4), new Foo, new Bar)
  println(test.x)
  println(test.y)
  processA(test)
}
```